# Function won't run on page load

Tags: javascript, events, smartsupp

I have changed the a function to load on page load but it will not do it.

The [original code](https://developers.smartsupp.com/chat/banner#banner-update) which runs with a link:

```
function updateBannerText(text) {
    smartsupp('banner:set', 'bubble');
    smartsupp('banner:update', { text: text });
});

<a href="javascript:updateBannerText('Welcome')">Welcome</a>,
<a href="javascript:updateBannerText('This chat is awesome')">This chat is awesome</a>
```

My code which should run on page load:

```
function updateBannerText(text) {
        smartsupp('banner:set', 'bubble');
        smartsupp('banner:update', { text: "{$Artikel->cName}" });
}
window.onload = updateBannerText;
```

I have changed `updateBannerText(text)` to `updateBannerText()` but it was not possible to run it.

Comment: Maybe the PHP variable is not working? Have you tried opening JS console to see if there are any errors?

Comment: the code looks correct to me. Maybe something else cause it?

Comment: Can you create a [minimum, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: You'll be calling `updateBannerText` with no parameter when it's called at load time--so how do you expect it to know what text to display? You could try `window.onload = function() { updateBannerText('Hi, I loaded'); };`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have no errors and it will not work too. Also tested the way of @torazaburo too without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the Smartsupp widget itself only starts to load on the page load, so your `window.onload` function runs before the widget is properly initialized and thus has no effect. You can test this by delaying the banner update, which should have an effect:

```
window.onload = function () { setTimeout(updateBannerText, 5000) }
```

To get around this, you should attach your startup code to an appropriate [Smartsupp widget event](https://developers.smartsupp.com/chat/events), say, the [`rendered` event](https://developers.smartsupp.com/chat/events#events-rendered) for updating the banner:

```
smartsupp('on', 'rendered', function() {
    updateBannerText('whatnot')
})
```